# "Why the long face?" or "Why a long face?"?

Tags: articles, expressions

I learned that when someone looks unhappy, then you can ask him/her "Why do you have a long face?".
And I also learned that the expression can be shortened into "Why **the** long face?"

My question is, why not "Why **a** long face?"? Why "**the**"?
What's the logic behind choosing "Why **the** long face" over "Why **a** long face?"?
Google search results numbers show a huge preference of using the over a.

If it is an example of an ellipsis, shouldn't it be "Why **a** long face"?

My best guess is that we use "the" to indicate that we are using a shortened version of a common expression "why do you have a long face". "The" implies "*You know the expression, right*?"

Is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means "What is the reason for the long face that you have?"

Comment: I said it to my horse once.